# StreamWriter only shows the last input in saved textfile, first one becomes blank on new line

Tags: c#, winforms

**Instructions:**

As I enter: *Last Name*, *First Name*, *ID#*, *Class* and *Grade*. Press *"OK"*. Press *"Load"* (the entered information shows down below in a readonly TextBox). Now I enter it all again, Press *"OK"* and *"Load"* again (now you I see two lines of information).

Here is an **image** of my form: 
[image: Image of the form]

**What happens:**

When I hit Save As, save my txt-file somewhere and open it. It will show the last input on the first line, and a blank on the secound (which seems to be the first input, but now its blank)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace StudentGrades
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string status;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        writeButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = 
            new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\StudentGrades\StudentGrades\TextFile.txt"))
        {
            textBoxReadGrades.AppendText(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }

    writeButton.Enabled = true;

    }

    private async void writeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter =
            "TextDocuments|*txt.", ValidateNames = true})
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(textBoxFirstName.Text +
                    "      " + textBoxLastName.Text +
                    "      " + textBoxID.Text +
                    "      " + textBoxClass.Text +
                    "      " + textBoxGrade.Text);

                    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully saved", "Message",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = 
            new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\StudentGrades\StudentGrades\TextFile.txt"))

            sw.WriteLine(textBoxFirstName.Text +
                 "      " + textBoxLastName.Text +
                 "      " + textBoxID.Text +
                 "      " + textBoxClass.Text +
                 "      " + textBoxGrade.Text + "\n");

            status = StatusLabel.Text = 
            "Entry Saved";

        writeButton.Enabled = false;

    }

   private void GetInfo (string fileName)
    {
        textBoxReadGrades.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code only writes one line.  If you want to append to end then use following : StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName,true)

Answer (score 1):

You may use AppendText method to append text to the existing file instead of overwriting:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(sfd.FileName))
{
 ...
}
```